# Error trying to generate notes with reports package on R

Tags: r, bibtex, r-markdown, reproducible-research

I am trying to generate notes for the reports package https://github.com/trinker/reports/ ,  and followed the steps from the youtube video http://goo.gl/x9ulf0 . I did run the chunk Tyler has there http://goo.gl/XHouuc but when I try to generate the notes i keep getting the following error message:

```
> notes()
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 

Possible causes:

1) The main file directory is not set as the working directory
2) ~/ARTICLES/notes.xlsx or ~/ARTICLES/notes.csv does not exist
```

I then tried to set my working directory to different places and even to move the ARTICLES directory to my home ~ directory, but i keep getting the exact same message no matter where i place the wd. i read the source code for the notes function but couldn't figure out where the problem might be. the notes2 function also gives me the same error

here is my sessioninfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitcitations_0.4-7  bibtex_0.3-6         knitr_1.4.1          slidifyLibraries_0.3
[5] slidify_0.3.52       reports_0.2.0       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.4.7 formatR_0.9    httr_0.2       markdown_0.6.3
 [6] RCurl_1.95-4.1 rJava_0.9-4    stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.1    whisker_0.3-2 
[11] xlsx_0.5.1     xlsxjars_0.5.0 XML_3.95-0.2   xtable_1.7-1   yaml_2.1.8
```

any thoughts on what the problem might be?

Comment: I can replicate the problem and I know what the problem is but not how to fix it.  I am trying to be cleaner with my importing of functions.  I use `@importFrom xlsx read.xlsx` in the documentation.  Apparently, I need to include more because if you explicitly load `library(xlsx)` the `notes()` function works.  Ricardo this is a temporary fix but I need a permanent solution of how to import properly from xlsx..

Comment: PS you may want to check out the newer video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArHQjQyIS70 and also the Vignette for the package: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503/packages/reports_vignette.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ricardo Pietrobon Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Ok the problem is that the xlsx package relies on Depends and not Imports to load the call to `.jnew` from the rJava package.  This means if you have used `library(xlsx)` then `read.xlsx` works fine, however if only the `read.xlsx` is attached via namespace then rJava's `.jnew` is not called.  hence the error.  This is confirmed in that the NAMESPAE file for xlsx contains:

```
import("xlsxjars")    
exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
```

This became a problem because CRAN recently required more restrictive checks and I started using `importFrom` rather than `import` and relying on Depends.  I actually recieved a warning along these lines from Prof. Brian Ripley about relying on Depends.  At the time I didn't understand it but heeded it.  I now get exactly what he was talking about.

For the time being I have added `rJava` to the Depends field in the DESCRIPTION file.  This throws a NOTE in the CRAN check as I'm Depending but not importing and needs to be removed after xlsx is updated.

I opened an issue with the xlsx package in the link below regarding the problem.  Hopefully this gets fixed and uploaded soon.  In the mean time `notes()` should be operating fine.

https://code.google.com/p/rexcel/issues/detail?id=24&thanks=24&ts=1379267751

I opened an [issue at report's GitHub](https://github.com/trinker/reports/issues/42) concerning this and as I believe the original problem has been solved, further conversation can be directed [there](https://github.com/trinker/reports/issues/42).